# locale problem when running xterm in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04

I am new to Linux. When I run a Borealis application, the 'locale not supported by Xlib' error comes up:

...

xterm -T Borealis@127.0.0.1:15000 -geometry 80x10+20+600 -e ../..//src/src/borealis -d 127.0.0.1:15000

One processing node (Borealis) started.

Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C

Starting mytest

Mytest started

nghiatran@nghiatran-desktop:~/borealis/test/simple$ xterm -T mytest -geometry 200x30+200+30 -e .//mytest

Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C

---

There should be two windows opening. However I only see them appear and quickly quit.
Using locale command I got this result:

LANG=en_SG.utf8

LC_CTYPE="en_SG.utf8"

LC_NUMERIC="en_SG.utf8"

LC_TIME="en_SG.utf8"

LC_COLLATE="en_SG.utf8"

LC_MONETARY="en_SG.utf8"

LC_MESSAGES="en_SG.utf8"

LC_PAPER="en_SG.utf8"

LC_NAME="en_SG.utf8"

LC_ADDRESS="en_SG.utf8"

LC_TELEPHONE="en_SG.utf8"

LC_MEASUREMENT="en_SG.utf8"

LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_SG.utf8"

LC_ALL=

Does anybody know how to solve this problem. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try launching with LANG=C and see if that changes anything: `LANG=C xterm -T mytest -geometry 200x30+200+30 -e .//mytest`

"Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C" hints that it's already falling back to this, and the crash you're experiencing may be unrelated. Do you see any other errors or messages when the program quits?