# Getting a problem with Cardapio and Gajim, won't launch due to a locale problem?

Tags: locale

After an update yesterday, every time I try to run gajim or cardapio, this is what I get:

`(process:10142): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.`

I tried reinstalling cardapio and I'm still getting the problem.
Since both are written in python I was guessing it must be a problem with python but I can't see which update could have caused this problem. I'm at a loss as to what to do, since nothing in my searching has proven useful (a bunch of unanswered forum posts for what seems to be a similar, but non-fatal error).

EDIT: After following this answer [locale problem when running xterm in Ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4062/locale-problem-when-running-xterm-in-ubuntu-10-04/4079#4079), I am still at a loss as to a fix. I can launch the applications with LANG=C, but, I don't quite get how to make that default (if this is needed).

EDIT#2
In seeking a solution, I tried to run clicompanion, and this is what I get:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/clicompanion", line 27, in <module>
    idioma = get_language()
  File "/usr/bin/clicompanion", line 18, in get_language
    loc = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 513, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what in my sequence fixed the problem, but nothing I tried worked - until:

- I reinstalled the locales (language-support-*)

  - This did not fix the problem, as far as I could tell, but at this point I had not logged out.
- Logged out, logged in without changing anything.

  - this did not fix the problem, it would seem, as I still got an error.
- I logged out, changed the language I was logging in with, and logged into the recovery console to test again.

  - Somehow the problem seems to have fixed itself.